# Why migrating from MySQL 5.5 to 5.7 is refusing to connect?

Tags: mysql, tomcat, database-migration, mysql-connector, mysql-5.7

I am trying to upgrade from MySQL **5.5(port:3306)** to **5.7(port:3308)** and following changes i have made.

1. Install new MySQL service for 5.7.
2. Replace MySQL-connector-java from **v.3.1.11-bin.jar** to **v5.1.9.jar**
3. Change port in database.properties from 3306 to 3308.

But when i try to run application from local tomcat, it is throwing below exception.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Don't know what i am missing in this migration?
**Also:** *If I run both MySQL services, instead of 3308, application is trying to connect to older service 3306!!!*

Comment: Why did the MySQL port change from 3306 to 3308?  Can you verify that MySQL in fact is actually listening on port 3308?

Comment: Yes, @TimBiegeleisen, I have kept old SQL as it is. I also have tried to connect newer one via workbenach. It is connecting fine.

Comment: OK, Tomcat basically has nothing to do with MySQL.  Can you give more information about your Java app code which uses MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Basically we have got requirement to upgrade application's Java version and MySQL version as well.
So first I upgraded from JDK 1.6 to 1.8 and tested the app. It was working fine, so now i am trying to upgrade MySQL from 5.5 to 5.7.
Older MySQL is hosted on 3306 port and newer on 3308 because i have kept both MySQL services for backup purpose. 
So all i've done in install new sql on 3308, create db and tables, changed jdbc url of app from **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mgmttest** to **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/mgmttest**, replace mySQlconnector 3.1.11-bin.jar with 5.1.9.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use old drivers instead of new. This will solve the issue. Also make sure that database is having all tables and minimum required data available in new database.